# Training Stalls while saving checkpoint using pytorch

Tags: pytorch, save, checkpoint

I am trying to save checkpoint while using pytorch in google colab.
When save it after all epochs are complete - it gets saved successfully. But, when I save it inside the for loop using below code, training stalls forever and pointer gets stuck at the line torch.save(checkpoint,....). A little help would be very useful.
if np.mean(tmp_eval_rmse) < best_valid_loss:
checkpoint = {"epoch":epoch_i, "model_state":model.state_dict(), "optim_state": optimizer.state_dict()}
torch.save(checkpoint, "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Best_Model_Checkpoint.pth.tar")
best_valid_loss = np.mean(tmp_eval_rmse)

Regards,
Mithun Thakkar.

Comment: Hi, Just FYI - similar issue was faced with using Tensorflow as well by someone else.- github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32017 –

Comment: Also FYI - I am using this link for my project work - https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/07/transfer-learning-for-nlp-fine-tuning-bert-for-text-classification/#:~:text=perform%20text%20classification.-,What%20is%20Model%20Fine%2DTuning%3F,dataset%20would%20result%20in%20overfitting.